# SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I've got the following code in some example `index.php`:

```
<?php
try{
    $Client = new SoapClient("catalog.wsdl");
}catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
}

try{
    $response = $Client->orderProducts([5, 6, 4, 3]);
    echo $response;
}catch(Exception $e){
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Sadly, it throws a `SoapFault (looks like we got no XML document)`, but **there IS** a valid `catalog.wsdl` in the same directory where `index.php` gets called.

Comment: Do you just have a WSDL file or is there an actual service listening? All a WSDL file does is specify a *-WS service contract so if you're trying to generate some sort of proxy file, that's what you'd call. If you want to actually call a service, you'll need to specify a URL for it to get an XML stream back.

Comment: There is another PHP script defined as a service. So do I have to define the `.wsdl` with an URL?

Comment: Why not just query that script then instead of bothering with a WSDL?